# OnRender / onShow / appendHtml functions are not firing in backbone marionette composite view

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, marionette

The way we are binding our view in layout is:

```
App.main.currentView.ChartViewRegion.show(new ChartView({model:chartDataCollections}));
```

In ChartView initialization it is returning the model data correctly, but it not invoking other functions. What might be the reason for that? its working fine on the web and but when we wrap it with phonegap its not firing those events.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this Peter? I'm currently having issues getting a Backbone project using Marionette running.

Comment: Yes it was a problem with collection data providing to model. If you provide in exact format, there won't be any problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same problem, so i looked through the source code.

both onRender and onShow have been deleted form the source code... they no longer exist. they are still in the comments, and in the documentation, but the functions do not exist.. its killing me.

(we are using version  1.04)

So i am currently scratching my head and trying to work out who is controlling the development of Marionette, and how much else has changed.... it would appear that everything now needs to access the triggered events around rendering, rather than rely on these callbacks, but have not found any documentation to explain how it all works, or what is the best practise.